# start apache airflow scheduler and webserver when system boot (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, airflow

I tried to go through the airflow documentation. Still couldn't figure how to use upstart or systemd to start airflow webserver and scheduler.

Documentation is for Ubuntu 14.04. Is there any updates towards these two methods?

Any can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are both systemd and upstart configuration files for the different airflow components available in the github repo. See https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/tree/master/scripts/systemd and https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/tree/master/scripts/upstart.